# How do I move a custom domain from one appengine project to another?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two google Appengine projects, **projectA.appspot.com** and **projectB.appspot.com**.

I have a custom domain **myproject.com** which is fully setup, verified and working well, pointing to projectA.

I now want to move the myproject.com domain from projectA to projectB.

Anybody know the sequence of steps involved? The only the docs I can find describe the initial setup and verification, which I've already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to change the application alias, first remove the alias and then create the new one.

You don't have to change your domain DNS because it's configure to works with appengine yet, the change should not take too long.

The steps are:

1. Enter in admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppEngineApps: . Here you have to see the two projects. If you don't see all the projects you can add with the *add services* button [image: add services button]
2. Select projectA and delete the Web address **myproject.com** to use it in your projectB
3. Go back and select projectB and click *Add new URL* select your comain **myproject.com** with the subdomain **www**, it's important, the subdomaint couldn't be blank.

Now you can access to you projectB from the URL **www.myproject.com**, to access with the url **myproject.com** you have to configure it too, [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373?hl=en) you can see how to configure it.

Comment: what does "change the application alias" mean and on which Google site do I do that?

Comment: In https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppEngineApps: you can setup the domain to your App Engine Apps, you have to delete the domain and create the new Web address to projectB.

Comment: if you know how to do this, it would be great if you could list out the steps

Comment: I've updated the answer, I hope it is usefull for you.

Comment: Doesn't work. When I try to add [www   ]myproject.com I get "Invaild domain"

Comment: worked on the 3rd attempt. Only difference between other attempts is I left several minutes between deleting and recreating.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do this to migrate live Appengine application with custom domain from US to EU.

### Deploy projectB application

1. create new project `projectB` on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)
2. update appengine-web to have new appid (`projectB`)
3. `appengineUpdate` (I use `gradle` but use whatever you deploy with)
4. on GCP, pause task queues for projectA and projectB

### Backup projectA datastore

*Summarised from https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities*

1. `gcloud auth login`
2. `gcloud config set project projectA`
3. `export BUCKETA="gs://projectAbackup"`
4. `gsutil mb -c regional -l us-central ${BUCKETA}`
5. `export BUCKETB="gs://projectBbackup"`
6. `gsutil mb -c regional -l europe-west2 ${BUCKETB}`
7. `gcloud datastore export --namespaces="(default)" ${BUCKETA} --async`
8. View progress with: `gcloud datastore operations describe ASANJUhjjJjhjfjdueuHHkdkjHfkKJjgkkHJDhKdfjsosoduNnvuUuausdnNuU` // based on output from previous.

### Copy data from projectA bucket to projectB bucket

1. `gsutil -m cp -r ${BUCKETA} ${BUCKETB}/[PATH]` # PATH could be like: `2019-06-10T08:48:27_12345`

### import to projectB

1. `gcloud auth login`
2. `gcloud config set project projectB`
3. `gcloud datastore import ${BUCKETB}/[PATH]/[FILE].overall_export_metadata  --async` // Using `PATH` and `FILE` of backup to import (you may need to set up IAM roles)
4. View progress with: `gcloud datastore operations describe ASANJUhjjJjhjfjdueuHHkdkjHfkKJjgkkHJDhKdfjsosoduNnvuUuausdnNuU` // based on output from previous
5. Wait for import to complete

### Migrate custom domain mapping

1. delete custom domain in projectA in GCP: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains

   1. *Note: if you cannot delete the custom domains and see this message "All domains mapped to this application are shown below. Only owners of a domain may remove one of its mappings." you may have to re-verify ownership (I did for some inexplicable reason)*
2. add custom domain in projectB: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains
3. resume task queues for projectB
4. disable projectA in GCP (https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings)